# Logs exceeding 60 GBs

Tags: sharepoint-server, logs

I am on SharePont Server Standard 2010 and noticed that my log folder had increased to 60 GB, since it was first run on June 2012.

```
Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS
```

I notice that is compromised by the following type of text files:

```
PSCDiagnostics.txt
Servername.usage
Servername.log
```

I have noticed the following:

- The PSCDiagnostics files are about 400 KB and aren't many files.
- The usage files are created every 5 minutes and are about 10 MB.
- The log files are the biggest at 120 MB and are created every half
  hour.

I have to delete these files as they are taking way too much space, but wanted to know what would be the safest route to take or best practice.

Answer (score 2):

you did not mentioned which logs are bigger Usage or .log?

But i would check the Diagnostics logging on the central admin and make sure every thing is set to `Least critical event to report to the trace log` and `Least critical event to report to the event log`, this will help the reduce the log file size. 
check here for more information how to access and modify the logs settings.

[Configure diagnostic logging (Office SharePoint Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263501(v=office.12).aspx)

2nd guess is may be you have higher usage which cause heavy usage logs.

check this technet for more info. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261966(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: .log are about 20 MB. They are created every half hour. The usuage logs are about 2 MB and are created every 5 minutes.

Comment: what is retention days for .log files? which file is bigger?

Comment: I updated the post. So far I went into Diagnostic Logging and changed the Least critical event to report to the event log to Error and the Least critical event to report to the trace log to High. Also, I lowered the Maximum storage space for Trace Logs to 1 GB (It was originally at 1,000 GB). Not sure how to restart the services.

Comment: Open Windows Services and restart the SharePoint Trace Log Service or open a command prompt as administrator and run 
net stop SPTrace 
and then 
net start SPTrace

Comment: one more thing, i want to ask what is value in following boxes? Number of logs file & number of mintues to use a log file?

Comment: After lowering the values and restarting the Trace service, the .usage logs are still being created every 5 minutes at about 15 MB and the .log files every half hour at 20 MB. I can't find the "Number of log files" and "number of minutes to use a log file" setting.

Comment: I actually have SharePoint 2010 not 2007 as originally stated. I realized my error this after I [read this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/christwe/archive/2012/06/11/sharepoint-diagnostic-logging.aspx).